# display specific single record from database on click by user

Tags: php, database

i have a form and i am able to retrieve the data from database and display it.on display i used only 5 coloums to display and i want that if user click a specific row in it then new window should open which contains only data specified to that user.?? i have 20 columns in table and and id with auto increment?? how to display the data specified to a particular id clicked by user..?? when user first view the table with 5 columns and want more details he should click on that row and then data belonging to that id should be displayed only.!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a separate page which will show the data for the entry you've selected, so:

First page will contain a db selection and a loop like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT field_id, field_name, etc FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo '<a href="/path/to/show-info.php?id=' . $row['field_id'] . '">' . $row['field_name'] . '</a><br />';
}
```

`show-info.php` should have a db selection based on `id` in url:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0)
    echo 'There is a problem showing you more info about this product';
else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

   // do something with your extracted data

}
```

Comment: 11 detrfgdxgf sdfdsdg dfghdhyfy 0

Comment: this is how the table is displayed with 11 as id.. i want that when user click on this id he only get the record of 11th id open in new page. how will be database id compared to the click function of id..??

Comment: I didn't understand exactly your last question but when you show the links in first page you'll also get the id of each entry and send it via url with the `id` variable. So in the second page where you'll get the information from database using this id `$_GET['id']` will return you all information about the entry you precedently selected.

Comment: function displaysales()
{
if(!$this->DBLogin())
{$this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
 return 'No Presentations available';}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $this->saleform");
enter code hereif(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
{return "";
}
else{ 
$data ="<table cellspacing='10px';>";
$data .="<th width='50px' >"."Id" ."</th><th width='130px' >"."Registered By" ."</th><th width='120px'>"." First Name "."</th><th width='120px'>"." Last name "."</th><th width='120px' >"."Mobile No" ."</th><th width='120px'>"."Email Id"."</th><th width='140px'>"."Registration Date"."</th>";

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{$data .= "<tr >" ;
$data .= "<td  >". $row['id']."</td><td  >". $row['registered_by']."</td><td>".$row['first_name']."</td><td>".$row['last_name']."</td><td>".$row['mobile_no']."</td><td>".$row['email_no']."</td><td>  ".$row['date_registration']."</td>";
$data .="</tr>";}
}this my function for first retrieve of data which has 5 coulmns and many rows and if user click on this row or id he should get all the 20 coloumns detail in new page or window?will this work with what u have provided me with above code?i am new to php and sorry if i am wiered in it

Comment: yes.. if you send the id to the next page you'll make a new selection from database with all columns that you need, like I explained to you in the answer. After that you can show them into the page

Comment: thanks for the answer and i will be very delighfull if u explain me url concept also like how it worked..?

Comment: There are 4 ways to send variables from one page to another: 1. GET method which are sended via url variables and/or html forms; 2. POST method which is sended via html forms; 3. SESSION variables which are stored in current session; 4. COOKIES which are stored on user local machine; Please visit http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp for more info about GET method which I've presented you in the answer